# Can rendered attributes handle Set .contains method?

Tags: apex, visualforce, set

I have a set named "voted" in my controller and I want to use that set on my visualforce to check if the user already voted on the idea.

```
public Set<String> voted = new Set<String>();
```

I used the voted for assigning the styleclass for the commandlink but it's not working.

```
<apex:commandLink styleClass="{!IF(voted.contains(i.Id+'-'+u.id+'-Down'),light-blue-link,light-gray-link)}" action="{!downVote}" reRender="forum, messages" status="loading">
```

Answer (score 2):

No. The best you can do is `Map<String, Boolean>` to track if your data keys exist.

Please note, you have to actually use property notation in order to reference *any* property on your controller, supported markup syntax or no.

**Controller**

```
public Map<String, Boolean> mySetContains { get; private set; }
```

**Markup**

```
styleClass="{!IF(mySetContains[key], 'foo', 'bar')}"
```

This approach will only work if you can pre-compute all keys which might be checked.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I used the Map <String, Boolean> but it's not working

Comment: styleClass="{!IF(CONTAINSKEY(voted[i.Id+'-'+u.id+'-Down'],true),'light-blue-link','light-gray-link')}"

Comment: No if you have `Map<String, Boolean> mySetContains` you then do `{!IF(mySetContains[key])}`

Comment: styleClass="{!IF(voted.[i.Id+'-'+u.id+'-Down'],'light-blue-link','light-gray-link')}

Comment: I got an error "Unknown property 'CustomerSuccess_IdeasController.voted'"

Comment: This is why you should include ***verbatim error messages*** in your question posts...